# Validate username and email crashed and cannot insert to firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

The apps cannot insert any data to the database while this line of code makes error to the apps.

```
ref.child(uid).orderByChild("username").equalTo(validateName).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Username Taken. Please try another one", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Besides, the uid is the code gather the email from the email authentication part.

```
private FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
private FirebaseUser ur = auth.getCurrentUser();
db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref = db.getReference();
    if (ur != null){
        uid = ur.getEmail();
    }
```

The error from logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.example.rex.ota30, PID: 30205
                                                                   com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase Database path: rexyou0831@gmail.com. Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqh.zzjm(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqh.zzjn(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.example.rex.ota30.Register$4.onComplete(Register.java:203)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzc$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Answer (score 1):

As your error said, `Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'`. This means that Firebase does not allow you use in the key symbols those symbols. Because of that, you need to econde the email address like this:

> name@email.com -> name@email,com

To achieve this, i recomand you using the following methods:

```
static String encodeUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    return userEmail.replace(".", ",");
}

static String decodeUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    return userEmail.replace(",", ".");
}
```

Comment: When you add the email address to your database, you need to encode it first. Your email address should look like this: `name@email,com`. This a common practice within Firebase.

Comment: Not working. I did put the code encodeUserEmail(email) but it still cannot be replace.

Comment: If you have other records that are wrong in your database, you need to delete them and add fresh and correct data. It must work.

Comment: See my answer. I insert 3 places also cannot replace.

Comment: You need to encode the email before adding to the object of the class User. Use ->`encodeUserEmail(em);` and then use `User u = new User (un, pw, ag, em, gd, pn, ad, pc, ps);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153665/discussion-between-rex-you-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: yes but the user still can register even the username detected duplicated from the database

Comment: Then just use exists() method on the `dataSnapshot` object to verify for uniqness. Does it work?

Comment: see my latest answer

Answer (score 0):

[image]Now currently my code will be like this so where to change that to exists?

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    for(DataSnapshot c : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                        String vun = c.child("username").getValue().toString();

                        if (vun.equalsIgnoreCase(usnm)){

                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Username Taken. Please try another one.", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;

                        }
                    }//end of for loop
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {


                }
            });// end of addvalue
```