# How to save data in firebase under a variable using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, variables, firebase-realtime-database

I have a question regarding saving data under a variable in firebase. I want to use the user's email to save data from a planner. I can save it with the code shown bellow, but just under the todoArray. I want todoArray to be stocked in every user's email. The problem is that I can't use the variable Email to save data in realtime database. Can you help me please?

```js
$('.save').on('click', function() {
  var Email=localStorage.getItem("email");
  window.alert(Email)
    todoArray = [];

    for (i = 1; i < 25; i++) {
        let todoValue = $('#' + i).val();

        let todoObject = {
            todoHour: i,
            todoItem: todoValue
        }

        firebase.database().ref(Email).set({todoArray});
        todoArray.push(todoObject);
}
})
```

Comment: "I can't use the variable Email to save data in realtime database" Why not? What is keeping you from doing that? Is there an error message?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I used the variable as you can see, but in firebase it doesn't save any data, only if i write a word like ref("email") and then everything will be saved under the word email, but I don't want this.

Comment: Error: child failed: path argument was an invalid path = "iustina.tibirna@outlook.com". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"  I found this error. This is the email that was stocked in the variabile Email

Comment: The email address contains a `.`, which (as the error message says) is not allowed in keys in the database. To be able to use the email address, remove the `.` from it - or encode the `.` with something that **is** allowed. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/46049837 and more from https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+email+address+as+key

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i can't remove the . because is part of the email adress. But how can I use the id or something else?

Comment: The links I provided show how to encode the `.` into something else, like for example a `,`, which conveniently cannot appear in an email address, but **can** be used in Firebase keys.