# V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service I can't write any values in firebase (android) java

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

When i signup with firebase auth the signup are completed successfully but after signing up
i try to write some information about user but the problem nothing are writing in firebase realtime database.

> SignupFragment

```
package com.ar.team.company.app.ar_app_25.ui.sign.up;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.ar.team.company.app.ar_app_25.ui.sign.sign.SignActivity;
import com.ar.team.company.app.ar_app_25.databinding.FragmentSignupBinding;
import com.ar.team.company.app.ar_app_25.ui.sign.way.SignWayActivity;
import com.ar.team.company.app.ar_app_25.utils.Utils;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Objects;

@SuppressWarnings({"FieldCanBeLocal", "ConstantConditions"})
public class SignupFragment extends Fragment implements OnCompleteListener<AuthResult> {

    // This for control the Fragment-Layout views:
    private FragmentSignupBinding binding;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private FirebaseUser user;
    private DatabaseReference reference;
    private ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the fragment layout:
        binding = FragmentSignupBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot(); // Get the fragment layout root.
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NotNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // Initializing:
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        progress = Utils.dialog(requireContext(), "Creating your amazing account!", "Please be patient");
        // Developing:
        binding.signupButton.setOnClickListener(this::signupNewAccount);
    }

    // This is signup method:
    private void signupNewAccount(View view) {
        // Getting data:
        String userGmail = Objects.requireNonNull(binding.userGmailEditText.getText()).toString();
        String userPass = Objects.requireNonNull(binding.userPassEditText.getText()).toString();
        // Creating new firebase account:
        if (!userGmail.isEmpty() && !userPass.isEmpty() && userGmail != null && userPass != null) {
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userGmail, userPass).addOnCompleteListener(this);
            progress.show();
        } else {
            Utils.showResult(binding.parentLayout, "Please enter your info", "Close", null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if (task.isComplete() && task.isSuccessful()) {
            // Initializing:
            user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Utils.FIREBASE_MAIN_REFERENCE).child(user.getUid());
            // Setting our data:
            HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put(Utils.FIREBASE_NAME_VALUE, Objects.requireNonNull(binding.userNameEditText.getText()).toString());
            data.put(Utils.FIREBASE_IMAGE_VALUE, "default");
            // Dismissing the progress:
            progress.dismiss();
            // Setting the value:
            Task<Void> voidTask = reference.setValue(data);
            voidTask.addOnCompleteListener(task1 -> {
                if (task1.isComplete() && task1.isSuccessful())
                    Utils.showResult(binding.parentLayout, "Signed Successfully", "LOGIN", this::restartMethod);
            });
            voidTask.addOnFailureListener(Throwable::printStackTrace);
        } else {
            progress.hide();
            Utils.showResult(binding.parentLayout, "Something wrong!", "Close");
        }
    }


    private void restartMethod(View view) {
        // Initializing:
        requireActivity().finish();
        Intent signIntent = new Intent(requireContext(), SignActivity.class);
        // Put extras:
        signIntent.putExtra(SignWayActivity.WAY_ACTION, SignWayActivity.WAY_ACTION_IN);
        // Developing:
        requireActivity().startActivity(signIntent);
    }
}
```

> Utils class

```
package com.ar.team.company.app.ar_app_25.utils;
    
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    
    import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
    
public class Utils {
    
        // Firebase constance:
        public static final String FIREBASE_MAIN_REFERENCE = "Users";
        public static final String FIREBASE_NAME_VALUE = "name";
        public static final String FIREBASE_IMAGE_VALUE = "image";
        // Firebase storage constance:
        public static final String FIREBASE_STORAGE_IMAGES_LOCATION = "profile_images";
        public static final String FIREBASE_STORAGE_IMAGES_URL = "gs://ar-app-25.appspot.com/" + FIREBASE_STORAGE_IMAGES_LOCATION + "/";
    
        // Showing progressDialog:
        public static ProgressDialog dialog(Context context, String title, String content) {
            // Initializing:
            ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(context);
            // Developing:
            progress.setTitle(title);
            progress.setMessage(content);
            progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            // Returning:
            return progress;
        }
    
        // Showing snackBar:
        public static void showResult(View view, CharSequence sequence, CharSequence action, View.OnClickListener listener) {
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, sequence, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
            snackbar.setAction(action, listener);
            snackbar.show();
        }
    
        public static void showResult(View view, CharSequence sequence, CharSequence action) {
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, sequence, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
            snackbar.setAction(action, v -> Log.d("SnackBarAction", "Close"));
            snackbar.show();
        }
    }
```

> Android studio (run)

```
08/02 01:16:29: Launching 'app' on AR-Device.
Install successfully finished in 228 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.ar.team.company.app.ar_app_25/com.ar.team.company.app.ar_app_25.ui.main.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 8807 on device 'AR-Device [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/studio.deploy: Finished instrumenting
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
    No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:51 and remote module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:51
    Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite, version >= 51
V/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( XMjhchhlFHWfnzPK06se4Ib2Cjg1 ).
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to fallback implementation
V/FA: onActivityCreated
V/FA: App measurement collection enabled
V/FA: App measurement enabled for app package, google app id: com.ar.team.company.app.ar_app_25, 1:405566473108:android:dce00fe1a9ce3130d70581
I/FA: App measurement initialized, version: 42041
    To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
    To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.ar.team.company.app.ar_app_25
D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
W/y.app.ar_app_2: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 27797530
I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xc6f8f040, tid 8838
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xc6f8e240: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xc6f8e240: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb8284030) (first time)
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
    HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xc6f8eef0, tid 8838
D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
    allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x387ffe000 size 0x2000
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 5
W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 3007
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 27800538
V/FA: onActivityCreated
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 27800652
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 1944
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 27802596
V/FA: onActivityCreated
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 27802943
I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 3812 bytes, containing 1 windows, 30 views
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( wyVwxXzIKEgcHOMbK9hbc8KP9PY2 ).
    Notifying auth state listeners about user ( wyVwxXzIKEgcHOMbK9hbc8KP9PY2 ).
```

So i think the problem is something like i don't have the access for firebase realtime database
but i'm not very sure about that because this is my first time working with firebase

& thanks for all.

Comment: If you downloaded the `google-services.json` before creating the database, and if the database is not in the default/US region, the SDK may not be able to determine the URL of your database. You can try specifying the database URL in this call: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("database URL here").getReference(Utils.FIREBASE_MAIN_REFERENCE)`.

Comment: it's give me an error

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ar.team.company.app.ar_app_25, PID: 13156
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase Database path: https://ar-app-25-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/. Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.Validation.validatePathString(Validation.java:45

Comment: So most likely you are using one of those forbidden symbols, right? If it's the email, try to [encode/decode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46050018/5246885) it.

Comment: It seems you're passing the URL to the wrong call. You need to pass it to `getInstance("URL here")`, not to `getReference(...)` or `child(...)`.

Comment: now the error is gone but the same no written data in realTime database but the signup process is success but no data:

Comment: and it;s give me this

Comment: W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.